# javascript if dropdown selected then send the info (data) to a list

Tags: javascript

I have three dropdown,

1. select side: left or right. other one
2. select material; alu and Inox, and the other one
3. select size: 22, 17 or 46

I need the selected data on a table. example:
    as left and alu and `22` are selected, I need the information
   `line 1 = 13857` 
    `Line 2 = 13861`
   `Line 3 = 17989`
Other example:
    as right and inox and 17 are selected, I need the information on the 
   `Line 1 = 13856`
    `Line 2 = 21839`
    `Line 3 = 17988`

[image]

**EDIT from comments**:

I have three list :

List 1: `Code 22 =13857 Code 17 = 13856 Code 46 = 13855`

List 2 : `Aluminiun left =13681 Aluminiun right =13862 Inox left = 21838 Inox right = 21839`

List 3 : `Code L22 = 17989 Code R22 = 17990 Code L17 = 17987 Code R17 = 17988 Code L46 = 17991 Code R46 = 17992`

With three dropdown should be connected with the choices:

Dropdown 1: left or right

Dropdown 2: 22, 17 or 46

Dropdown 3: aluminium or inox

With the combination of all three dropdown I should have one list,

Code A on line 1: from dropdown 2, example if 22 is selected, then should appear the number 13857

Code B on line 2: information from combination dropdown 1 and dropdown 3.

For example : left and inox, then should appear the number 21838

Code C on line 3: information from combination dropdown 1 and dropdown 2.

For example: 22 and left, then should appear the number 17989 I have a button to calculate the function.

The description of the problem is not well done. My work as example: [link](http://jsbin.com/sitesasuwo/edit?html,output) and hier an example for the Dropdown or if it better with radio button. [link](http://jsbin.com/topokoqeqa/edit?html,output) It is possible to add more var. For example: var S22 = 13857 var S17 = 13856 var S22 = 13855 var A22L = 13857

Comment: Hallo K0pernikus, thank you for your correction, any idea what can I do. Gruss

Comment: maybe you write something more, what you need and what you have done so far.

Comment: I have three list :
List 1: 
Code 22 =13857
Code 17 = 13856
Code 46 = 13855
List 2 :
Aluminiun left =13681
Aluminiun right =13862
Inox left = 21838
Inox right = 21839
List 3 :
Code L22 = 17989
Code R22 = 17990
Code L17 = 17987
Code R17 = 17988
Code L46 = 17991
Code R46 = 17992
Whit three dropwon should be connected with the choices:
Dropdown 1: left or right
Dropdown 2: 22, 17 or 46
Dropdown 3: aluminium or inox.

Comment: With the combination of all three dropdown I should have one list, 
Code A on line 1: from dropdown 2, example if 22 is selected, then should appear the number 13857 
Code B on line 2: information from combination dropdown 1 and dropdown 3. For example : left and inox, then should appear the number 21838
Code C on line 3: information from combination dropdown 1 and dropdown 2. For example: 22 and left, then should appear the number 17989
I have a button to calculate the function.
Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, the description of the problem is not well done. My work as example: [link](http://jsbin.com/sitesasuwo/edit?html,output)       and hier an example for the Dropdown or if it better with    radio button. [link](http://jsbin.com/topokoqeqa/edit?html,output)                                            It is possible to add more var. For example:

var S22 = 13857
var S17 = 13856
var S22 = 13855
var A22L = 13857

Comment: Instead of adding more and more information as comment, use the possibility to edit your question to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you need a data structure like this:

```
{
    "line1": {
        "17": 13856,
        "22": 13857,
        "46": 13855
    },
    "line2": {
        "left": {
            "alu": 13861,
            "inox": 21838
        },
        "right": {
            "alu": 13862,
            "inox": 21839
        }
    },
    "line3": {
        "left": {
            "17": 17987,
            "22": 17989,
            "46": 17991
        },
        "right": {
            "17": 17988,
            "22": 17990,
            "46": 17992
        }
    }
}
```

This allows to select a wanted line and get the value for the selected items in the selection.

The access is quite simple with

```
// example for 17 right inox
data.line1['17']
data.line2['right']['inox']
data.line3['right']['17']
```

Altogether in a working example:

```js
var data = {
    line1: {
        '22': 13857,
        '17': 13856,
        '46': 13855,
    },
    line2: {
        left: {
            alu: 13861,
            inox: 21838
        },
        right: {
            alu: 13862,
            inox: 21839
        }
    },
    line3: {
        left: {
            '22': 17989,
            '17': 17987,
            '46': 17991,
        },
        right: {
            '22': 17990,
            '17': 17988,
            '46': 17992,
        }
    }
};

function getCode() {
    function getValue(name) {
        return document.order[name].options[document.order[name].selectedIndex].value
    }

    var size = getValue('size'),
        side = getValue('side'),
        material = getValue('material');
    document.getElementById('line1').innerHTML = data.line1[size];
    document.getElementById('line2').innerHTML = data.line2[side][material];
    document.getElementById('line3').innerHTML = data.line3[side][size];
}
```

```html
<form name="order">
    Size
    <select name="size" onchange="getCode();">
        <option value="22">22 mm</option>
        <option value="17">17 mm</option>
        <option value="46">46 mm</option>
    </select>
    Side
    <select name="side" onchange="getCode();">
        <option value="left">Links</option>
        <option value="right">Rechts</option>
    </select>
    Material
    <select name="material" onchange="getCode();">
        <option value="alu">Alu</option>
        <option value="inox">inox</option>
    </select>
</form>
<p>
    Line 1: <span id="line1"></span><br />
    Line 2: <span id="line2"></span><br />
    Line 3: <span id="line3"></span>
</p>
```

Comment: Hallo Nina, Perfect. exactly what I want. I have put the script in my example, but it does not work like your example. What I have done wrong? [NEW EXAMPLE](http://jsbin.com/guzosiyuji/edit?html,output) Danke.

Comment: no body tag? not initialised? pleaes have a look to the browser tools with `[F12]`

Comment: Sorry, I can't fix it, no idea. Where and what to do.

Comment: sorry to say. just start over with a really empty html document with just the basics. then put the part who need functionality in and at last bring in the design, look and feel.

Comment: hello, thank you. Now it's ok, it works on the "JS Bin" page, [HIER](http://jsbin.com/melulamusu/edit?html,output) but now my problem is that in my own page donn't work. I use it in a SharePoint (MS SharePoint designer), > the information on the top  from SharePoint
>
><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:mso="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:msdt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882" xmlns:v="urn:schemas->microsoft-com:vml">

Comment: please ask a new question for that.